# maintaining anchor in http redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, anchor

So right now I have a lot of links on a website pointing to an old HTML file.  Most of these links are tied to sectional hash anchors down the page.  Currently that HTML page redirects to a new version of the page, which is a PHP file containing the same anchors.  I am using a basic javascript redirect script in the .  Is there a way that I can get the anchor (if the referring link contained one) and append that to the redirect?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Links and anchors are the same thing in HTML so I don't understand "Most of these links are anchored on the page." I also don't understand what it means to "append [an anchor] to a redirect".

Comment: I'm guessing they're talking about the hash fragment of a link.

Comment: sorry for ambiguity, yes they are tied to an anchor down the page for example ../website.html#anchor, right now it forwards to ../website.php, but I wonder since there are dozens of anchors if it is possible to preserve that in the redirect.  I have edited my question to remove this confusing wording.

Comment: Ah OK. The part after the # in URLs is sometimes also called the fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the hash part of the URL using

```
window.location.hash
```

Please note that the value returned includes the hash symbol. So when you append it to the URL, you do not have to append a hashtag as well.

so:

```
var newURL = 'http://newURL'+window.location.hash;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  Google searches and searches here did not turn up what I was looking for, it's great to be able to get quick help from real people.